# ExtJS Controller Selector for Events

Tags: javascript, controller, extjs4, extjs

I have a view and a controller. The view has menu under button of which items when clicked will be handled by controller. The event is never caught by controller if I put class selector but it works if I remove class selector.

Have a look at my code.

View

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Add Tab',
    cls: 'button',
    menu: Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
        cls: 'addMenu',
        items: [{
            text: 'One'
        }, {
            text: 'Two'
        }]
    })
});
```

And Controller

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.TabController', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init : function() {
        this.control({
            'menu[cls=addMenu]' : {
                'click' : this.addTab
            }
        });
    },

    addTab : function(a, b, c, d) {
        console.log(a, b, c, d);
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried using `class` instead of `cls`?

Comment: Yes I have tested this as well. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem the other way around.

View

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Add Tab',
    cls: 'button addTab',
    menu: Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
        cls: 'addMenu',
        items: [{
            text: 'One'
        }, {
            text: 'Two'
        }]
    })
});
```

And Controller

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.TabController', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init : function() {
        this.control({
            'button[cls=button addTab] > menu' : {
                'click' : this.addTab
            }
        });
    },

    addTab : function(a, b, c, d) {
        console.log(a, b, c, d);
    }
});
```

This works great!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should wrap class name into quotes like

```
'menu[cls="addMenu"]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, '=' operator is more suited for object properties other than CSS classes, while '~=' operator will work best with properties that hold lists of whitespace-separated CSS classes.